# Error when creating the table : Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What is the problem in my code?

```
    public class AppUserMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppUser> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true);
            builder.HasMany(m => m.Essays).WithOne(m => m.AppUser).HasForeignKey(m => m.AppUserId);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class AppRoleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppRole>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppRole> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.HasMany(m => m.AppUsers).WithOne(m => m.AppRole).HasForeignKey(m => m.AppRoleId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>, ITable
    {
        public List<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, ITable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; } = "default.png";
        #nullable enable
        public string? AppUserRole { get; set; }
        #nullable disable
        public bool Ban { get; set; } = false;

        public List<Essay> Essays { get; set; }

        public AppRole AppRole { get; set; }
        public int AppRoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your migration file that causes the error?

Comment: We need to know where/when the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for answering. I solved the issue by changing a couple of things in my code.

This is my solution code(you can see the changes):

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, ITable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; } = "default.png";
        public bool Ban { get; set; } = false;

        public List<Essay> Essays { get; set; }

#nullable enable
        public AppRole? AppRole { get; set; }
        public int? AppRoleId { get; set; }
#nullable disable
    }
```

```
public class AppRoleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppRole>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppRole> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.HasMany(m => m.AppUsers).WithOne(m => m.AppRole).HasForeignKey(m => m.AppRoleId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
    }
```